# Can't get "webkit-appearance:none" to work

Tags: css, webkit

I can't get "webkit-appearance:none" to work. It is overridden somehow, even if I add "!important".

Any ideas? See pic below for the css in use.

http://oi60.tinypic.com/qytk53.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `webkit-appearance: none`, it's [`-webkit-appearance: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance). (you forgot the dash `-`)